# Why can I not parse Neo4jClient's query result (type string) into a Dictionary<string, string> using JsonConvert in C#

Tags: c#, json, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am trying to parse Neo4jClient's query result of paths (of type string) using JsonConvert.

I was able to parse the query result for nodes using this method:

```
var _gClient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
            _gClient.Connect();

            var result = _gClient.Cypher
                .Match("(n)")
                .Return(n => n.As<string>())
                .Results.ToList();

            result.ForEach(n =>
            {
                var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(n);
                Console.WriteLine("Keys: " + String.Join(",", dict.Keys));
                Console.WriteLine("Values: " + String.Join(",", dict.Values));
            });
```

However, when I tried to do the same with the query result of paths, JsonConvert's DeserializeObject method can't do the same thing:

```
var _gClient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
            _gClient.Connect();

            var result = _gClient.Cypher
                .Match("p=(a)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie {title:'The Matrix'})")
                .Return(p => new
                {
                    Nodes = Return.As<IEnumerable<string>>("EXTRACT(p in nodes(p) | p)"),
                    Relationships = Return.As<IEnumerable<string>>("EXTRACT(p in relationships(p) | p)")
                })
                .Results.ToList();

            foreach (var n in result)
            {
                foreach (var s in n.Nodes)
                {

                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(s);
                }
            }
```

The error was Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'extensions', line 2, position 17.

This is part of the string to be parsed:

```
{
  "extensions": {},
  "metadata": {
    "id": 8,
    "labels": [
      "Person"
    ]
  },
```

Does that mean Json can't deserialize empty braces? If so is there any other way I can parse this huge structure out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to deserialize into a `Dictionary<string,string>` but your JSON *isn't* a `Dictionary<string,string>` the error about the unexpected `{` is because for it to be a `Dictionary<string,string>` the JSON would look like:

```
{
  "Key1" : "Value1",
  "Key2" : "Value2"
}
```

The `{` on both `extensions` and `metadata` imply that there is an `object` there, not just a `string`. To  that end you can deserialize it using something like:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(s)
```

But if you want to access the properties, you may as well do:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(s)
```